# Ex-Macromedia Freehand junkies: what did you switch to?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector-graphics

Short and sweet.  My boss loved Freehand MX back in the day, and when Adobe killed it Illustrator just didn't click for him.  He's a fan of Inkscape, but it's a few features away from being feature complete for him (can't rebind shortcut keys to be similar to Freehand, for example).

Are there any ex-Freehand junkies out there?  If so, can any of you recomend an alternative to Illustrator or Inkscape?  We're a Mac shop, so I've taken a look at Opacity and Drawit, but I have no idea how they stack up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this likely won't be the accepted answer, if you company does this professionally, then Illustrator and Inkscape are the only options worth pursuing. I haven't used Inkscape, but I know it's becoming competitive.

I think the only realistic answer is to bite the bullet and learn the leading technology. You will never find an exact match to another program, however if he considers Inkscape to lack features, then you need to upgrade Illustrator. Similarly, if Inkscape lacks features, there aren't any other programs that won't have the same problem.

If it is only for occasional use, then perhaps Inkscape will suit your boss' needs once you get past the grace period of learning anything new.

Answer (score 1):

I like old Freehand 10 myself :-)

My recommendation is.... Create a Feature Request in [Inkscape's Launchpad Bug Tracker](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+filebug) --

Comment: Inkscape won't even import Freehand files at present, so it's not really an option for folks who have a decade or two of old files. :(